# How to Listen for Channel Type Changes (Public to Private and Vice Versa) in Slack Events?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I need to listen for channel type changes in Slack, like when a public channel becomes private or vice versa, for channels where my app is a member.

I couldn't find relevant events in the [Slack Events API](https://api.slack.com/events?filter=Events). Any workarounds or suggestions?
Thanks!